# Conditional Discount with cart via PayPal buttons

Tags: html, paypal, conditional-statements, discount

I use a PayPal shopping cart via their PayPal buttons to sell sewing patterns on my website and I would like to set up a conditional discount for my two types of items.  I would like the customer to receive $2.00 off their order if they buy both an A pattern and a B pattern (but no discount if they buy two B patterns or 3 A patterns, etc).

I have found various discount options for individual items by using their HTML variables (discount_amount, discount_num, etc.), but have not been able to find a way to create a discount that is reliant on two items.  I do not care if I end up with something automatic, or whether the customer uses some sort of promo code, but right now I am just refunding customers the $2.00, which is a hassle, and also feels less professional.  I also don't care if the discount technically gets applied to one item, or the entire order.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks!
Mattie

Comment: Not really. Payments standard doesn't do complex pricing like that. You'd have to switch to using your own cart and pass just the payment info at the end to consider this

Comment: Look around this site, has quite a bit on coupon var for PayPal buttons. Hope it helps.http://ccaples.com/index.php/basic-scripts

Comment: Thank you. I was hoping I would be able to add some sort of conditional code, but I think I only have access to the code of the buttons, not the general cart itself.  And I don't think there's a way for the button to be able to look and see if another button is in the cart.

Do you think it is possible through one of these sort of extra cart systems run by PayPal? developer.paypal.com/docs

Comment: Another thought would be if there was a way to apply a discount if the cart total was between $x - $xx.